# comparing blank variable using if statement

Tags: bash, if-statement

When i am comparing a blank variable with a string i am getting below error

```
[: !=: unary operator expected
```

Below is line in my script

```
if [ $monthlystatus = Completed ];then

command x
```

When i try to change this as below

```
if [ "$monthlystatus" = Completed ];then

command x
```

It does not give me expected result i.e. if statement give me wrong result.
For example when i am using double quote and even the value of variable monthlystatus is equal to Completed but still command x is not executed.

Below is the real code .

```
if [ $monthlystatus != Failed ] && [ $monthlystatus != Aborted ];then

cat /home/a-hkataria/objectstatus_filesystem2.txt /home/a-hkataria/objectstatus_filesystem3.txt > /home/a-hkataria/objectstatus_filesystem4.txt

awk '$2 = $2 FS "Yes"'  /home/a-hkataria/objectstatus_filesystem4.txt

else

cat /home/a-hkataria/objectstatus_filesystem2.txt /home/a-hkataria/objectstatus_filesystem3.txt > /home/a-hkataria/objectstatus_filesystem4.txt

awk '$2 = $2 FS "No"'  /home/a-hkataria/objectstatus_filesystem4.txt

fi
```

So in case variable `monthlystatus` is blank it is giving me error and when i use the double quote even value of variable is `Completed` but still it is not displaying `yes` in second column.

Comment: "does not work" is not a problem description. Please read [mcve].

Comment: Given a example

Comment: That's not an example (it's not complete or verifiable). Show real code.

Comment: Updated question with real code.

Comment: That's still not complete/verifiable. Nothing in your code sets `monthlystatus` so how can it be `Complete`?

Comment: Is it possible your `monthlystatus` variable contains extra characters (such as spaces) that would cause the comparison to fail?

Comment: I am printing the value of variable monthlystatus to verify its value before above code

Comment: @HiteshKataria, use `set -x` to log variables' values in an unambiguous way, or `printf 'monthlystatus=%q\n' "$monthlystatus"`. You can't trust `echo`.

Comment: @HiteshKataria, ...to be clear, the likely scenario here is that the *actual* value is something like `$'Completed\r'` or `'Completed '` instead of really being `Completed`. If you `echo "$monthlystatus"`, those two look exactly the same. This is why I suggested some better means of logging the actual value above.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951336/how-to-debug-a-bash-script

Comment: Let me try this please to check the if there is any space. Thanks

Comment: @CharlesDuffy when i use echo "XX$monthlystatusXX" it is printing XX only so what does it mean?

Comment: @HiteshKataria  It means variable `monthlystatusXX` is unset or contains a null string (unless `set -e` is active in which case not getting an error means it is set but contains a null string).  Use the technique suggested by @CharlesDuffy, but it you really want to try expanding the string this way, add braces so that the shell uses the right variable name : `echo "XX${monthlystatus}XX"`.

Comment: @Fred Yep bad suggestion on my part, didn't test it.

Comment: @HiteshKataria, I didn't suggest `echo "XX$monthlystatusXX"` -- that was someone else. I suggested either running your script with `bash -x`, or using `printf 'monthlystatus=%q\n' "$monthlystatus"`.

Comment: Hi Charles after removing the space from value of monthlystatus it work for me. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach is correct. Need quote the variable. Demo:

```
while read -r line; do
    [ "$line" = Completed ] && echo "true1 for =$line=" || echo "false1 for =$line="
    [[ "$line" == Completed ]] && echo "true2 for =$line=" || echo "false2 for =$line="
    [[ "$line" =~ ^Completed$ ]] && echo "true3 for =$line=" || echo "false3 for =$line="
    echo
done <<EOF
Completed
completed
Completediano
not Completed
notCompleted

etc
EOF
```

output

```
true1 for =Completed=
true2 for =Completed=
true3 for =Completed=

false1 for =completed=
false2 for =completed=
false3 for =completed=

false1 for =Completediano=
false2 for =Completediano=
false3 for =Completediano=

false1 for =not Completed=
false2 for =not Completed=
false3 for =not Completed=

false1 for =notCompleted=
false2 for =notCompleted=
false3 for =notCompleted=

false1 for ==
false2 for ==
false3 for ==

false1 for =etc=
false2 for =etc=
false3 for =etc=
```